# Decisions without if statements

Tags: java

Here are the instructions:

```
/*
 * Write a method called isGameOver. The method should have three parameters, 
 * all integers and in this order: the player's score, the number of lives 
 * the player has remaining, the game level. The method should return true 
 * if the game is over and false otherwise, according to the following game
 * rule. The game continues only when the player has at least one life 
 * remaining and one of these conditions is met: 
 *   --The player is on level 1 and his/her score at least 1000. 
 *   --The player is on level 2 and his/her score at least 2000. 
 *   --The player is on any level and his/her score at least 3000. 
 *   
 * For example, the method call isGameOver(1500, 1, 2) should return true. 
 * 
 * DO NOT USE AN IF STATEMENT
```

And here is my code:

```
public static String isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {

    while (level == 1 && level < 1001)
        return "false";

    while (level == 2 && level < 2001)
        return "false";

     while (level == 3 && level < 3001)
        return "false";

    return "true";          
}
```

It's obviously not working, and I just have this feeling it's because I used a while loop. How can I make a decision without using an if statement?

Comment: Hint: `&&` and `||` use _short-circuit_ evaluation.

Comment: Also, this function seems to _always_ return `true` value. Reconsider the return type.

Comment: Did you mean to test the `score`?

Comment: Are you allowed to use secondary methods? Evaluating which level you are on with a simple `return` statement (e.g. `return level == 1`) would be useful in this scenario.

Comment: If level is equal to 1, then it is less than 1001. I think you meant `score < 1001`

Comment: And the method should return a boolean value, not a string

Comment: Most of the comments above addressed the problem with your checks, but you also are not using the lives variable.  Also, please do not just say "it's not working".  Please tell us what it is doing and why that isn't what you expect.

Comment: Notice, as well, that the acceptable conditions are "at least 1000" (not more than 1000) and so on.  I think you are attempting to check at least 1001, at least 2001, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a **readable** solution, then you can pretty much directly translate the problem description into code.

```
/**
* The game continues only when the player...
**/
private static boolean gameContinues(int score, int lives, int level) {
    // has at least one life
    boolean stillAlive = lives >= 1; 
    // is on level 1 and his/her score at least 1000
    boolean cond1 = (level == 1 && score >= 1000); 
    // is on level 2 and his/her score at least 2000
    boolean cond2 = (level == 2 && score >= 2000);
    // is on any level and his/her score at least 3000
    boolean cond3 = score >= 3000;

    // return true if has at least one life remaining and one of the conditions is met
    return stillAlive && (cond1 || cond2 || cond3);
}

// The function you want just returns the inverse of what is defined
public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
    return !gameContinues(score, lives, level);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
    return lives<1 || (level<3 && score<1000*level) || (score<3000 && level>2);
}
```

Testing this

```
isGameOver(900,1,1) // true
isGameOver(1900,1,1) // false
isGameOver(1900,1,2) // true
isGameOver(2900,1,2) // false
isGameOver(3000,1,5) // false
isGameOver(3000,0,5) // true
```

The three conditions *or*-ed together will return true if at least one is true.  We check in order

1. are we out of lives (`lives<1`)?
2. did we fail the score conditions for levels 1 and 2 (score conditions are just 1000 points per level)?
3. did we fail the score condition for levels 3 and up (which all have the 3000 points requirement)?

If any of these conditions are true, we return true.  Otherwise we return false.

Comment: I'm too tired to see if that boolean logic is equivalent to my answer :)

Comment: @cricket_007 it is, other than the the way I combined levels 1 and 2 whereas you broke them apart.  And of course, you inverted the problem to test if the game is still going first.

Answer (score 1):

Can try something like this. I have not checked the exact conditions. This is more of a sample program.

```
public static String isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
    String result = "false";

   switch (level){
     case 1:
       result= score>1000 ? "true" : "false";
       break;
     case 2:
       result= score>2000 ? "true" : "false";
       break;
     default:
       result= score>3000 ? "true" : "false";
    return result;
   }
```

**Edit:** : People are pointing out to use boolean as return type instead of String. As i already called out the purpose is to show how to replace the if-else conditions not to write the entire program. So please consider.

Comment: Question says `DO NOT USE AN IF STATEMENT`

Comment: _DO NOT USE AN IF STATEMENT_. As stupid as it is, it's a part of question.

Comment: Could just `return score > value` for each case.

Comment: @cricket_007: it will return a boolean value, we want to return string

Comment: No, it doesn't return a boolean value... Where in the instructions does it say return `"true"`? It says `true`, which is different than `"true"`

Comment: @cricket_007: yeah in the instructions it didn't mention it. I always more following the code which the guy had written. So took it from there. :)

Comment: you forgot another condition: The game continues only when the player has at least one life remaining and one of these conditions is met:

Comment: @Mansouritta: not writing the whole logic for the guy..Only explaining him the replacement of if-else.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {

    return ((level == 1 && score < 1001)
         || (level == 2 && score < 2001)
         || (level == 3 && score < 3001));
}
```

Comment: I don't think the function should return a string. You can just return the boolean value. Just negate the whole thing

Comment: The function should return a `boolean`. Also the logic in those statements is incorrect. Since `level` is always less than those numbers, no matter what level the player is on this will always return true.

Comment: This does not return the correct values.  `isGameOver(1500,1,2)` should be true, this returns false.  It also does not use the lives.

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
    public boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
    boolean hasLife = (lives >= 1);
    boolean condition1 = (hasLife && (level == 1) && (score >= 1000));
    boolean condition2 = (hasLife && (level == 2) && (score >= 2000));
    boolean condition3 = (hasLife && score >= 3000);
    return !(condition1 || condition2 || condition3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand where your logic went wrong in your `while` statements. The statements:

```
while (level == 1 && level < 1001){
    ...
}
while (level == 2 && level < 2001){
    ...
}
while (level == 3 && level < 3001){
    ...
}
```

will ALWAYS be true, therefor you will by default always return `"true"`. You need to be evaluating `score` in the second condition, not `level`. Also, the directions specify that you return a `boolean` not a `String` in this method, so your return type needs to be `boolean`.

You can just use the return statement to evaluate booleans, you do not necessarily need an `if` statement to prove if something is true or not. For example `return 1 == 0;` will return false. In your case:

```
public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level){

    while (level == 1 && lives > 0)
        return score < 1000;     // If score is greater than 1000, returns false, else true

    while (level == 2 && lives > 0)
        return score < 2000;     // If score is greater than 2000, returns false, else true

    while (level >= 3 && lives > 0)
        return score < 3000;     // If score is greater than 3000, returns false, else true

    return true;                 // This accounts for if lives are not greater than 0
}
```

This method takes into account the level and the fact that the player has to have both more than one life AND a certain score in order to possibly return false. The use of the `return` statement as a `boolean` evaluator negates your need for `if` statements in this case.

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton! I really appreciate being told what I did wrong so that I can avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Comment: Of course, that's what learning is all about. This code should work nicely for you.

Comment: This will not work for levels greater than 3, e.g. isGameOver(3001, 1, 5) will return true

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {

return  level*1000 >= score;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't take lives into account

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in need of something like this

```
import java.util.*;    
class FirstApp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(2800,0,1)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(1800,1,2)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(2800,1,3)));

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(1000,1,1)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(2800,1,2)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(3800,1,1)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(3800,1,2)));
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(isGameOver(3800,1,3)));
        }

        public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
            if (lives < 1) return true;
            HashMap<Integer,Integer> levelScores = new HashMap();
            levelScores.put(1,1000);
            levelScores.put(2,2000);
            levelScores.put(3,3000);
            return (levelScores.get(level) > score)? true :false;
        }
    }
```

Sample output:

```
true
true
true

false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use switch statements which allows string value from java 1.7 . you can compute your expression and assign it to a string variable and then use that variable in switch.

Note: you cannot directly put expressions in switch cases .

Answer (score -1):

I would code it like:

```
public static boolean isGameOver(int score, int lives, int level) {
    while(lives > 0){
        switch (level) {
        case 1:
            return (score > 1000) ? false : true ;

        case 2:
            return (score > 2000) ? false : true ;

        case 3:
            return (score > 3000) ? false : true ;
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need a do while in this case ?

Comment: This is a copy from an existing answer as you can do `return score > 1000;` in each case

Comment: Actually you would want to `return score < 1000` since the value `true` means the game has ended.